# Internal server error with azure project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-express, internal-server-error

I am following this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2010/03/24/how-to-use-asp-net-forms-auth-with-sql-server.aspx  and I am now running the project. On running the project though I an getting an Internal server error: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. I have already altered the connection string in the web.config file as shown below but I am not sure if this is causing the problem or not.

Is there some way in which I can see the exact error and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical part in this configuration is network configuration. How are you making sure that Azure Cloud Service machine is able to connect your on-premise machine? Have you configured all the firewall and ports properly to make sure the connectivity is not an issue. With network specific problem you might get general error so you may need to troubleshoot network specific issue by yourself for correctness.

You could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh509003.aspx) updated document connecting on-premise SQL Server with Azure Cloud Service. This document uses Azure Connect (which is still on Beta and almost depricated) so you can understand how your network should be visible for your Windows Azure cloud application.

IF you don't want to use On-Premise SQL Server and want to use SQL Azure or Azure Storage then the forms authentication process could be much simpler. Here are more details if you wish to use it:

1. [Forms-Based Authentication with Windows Azure Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508987.aspx)
2. [Forms-Based Authentication with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508981.aspx)

Comment: I used the Forms-Based Authentication with SQL Azure tutorial and the connection has worked. When I try to register a new user though I keep getting an error: Please enter a different user name.

Any ideas why and how I can fix it? Thanks